# What does logging into the IDEA server let me do?

Tags: intellij-idea

In Intellij what does logging into the IDEA server allow me to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Original answer was about sharing setting using IntelliJ IDEA server feature. I has been replaced with the Settings Repository since then. Please [refer to the documentation for the details](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/sharing-your-ide-settings.html).

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that it required no configuration.

Comment: Hi @crazycoder, the link you provided does not work anymore, can you please update it ?